# How to get array of all `this` of an instance

Tags: c++, inheritance

Assuming when Button is clicked, the `btn_Click` event handler will be fired.

I have `sender`, a parameter that contains a reference to the control/object that raised the event. The sender portion will be a reference to the button which was clicked. In case the control raises the event to itself, abort the process (simply call return).

```
struct EventArgs { /* The arguments of the event */ };
struct A { int x; virtual ~A() = default; };
struct B { int y; virtual ~B() = default; };
struct C : public virtual A, public virtual B {
    void btn_Click(void* sender, EventArgs* e) {
       if (sender == static_cast<void*>(this)) return;
       else { /* Handle the event */ }
    }
};

int main() {
    A* a = new C();
    dynamic_cast<C*>(a)->btn_Click(a, nullptr);
}
```

Assuming sender is `a`, the above code `sender == this` will evaluate to false.

What can I do to make it return true? I think I need to create an array of all `this` pointers, then compare `sender` to all of them.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. At the very least have no compile errors from pasting your snippet.

Comment: @PasserBy I've edited the code to make it compile. http://cpp.sh/2r3di

Comment: Take the  sender by its base class type, not by `void*` https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7baebf14ef9663af

Comment: @jrok: Doesn't it seem likely that some sort of GUI framework is involved here that erases the type in the callback?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes. I was hoping OP would clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do need to compare to all subobjects, but it's better to write a function than to use an array:

```
struct C: A, B
{
    bool is(void* that) const
    {
        return this == that
            || static_cast<const A*>(this) == that
            || static_cast<const B*>(this) == that;
    }

    void btn_Click(void* sender, EventArgs* e) {
       if (this->is(sender)) return;
       // ...
    }
}
```

Note that the casts must be on `this`, not on `that`, so the compiler can generate the correct pointer adjustments based on the types.

Using `void*` is questionable, though - you may want to use something less generic and error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `void*` constraint comes from your GUI framework (this is common, and has some good reasons), I would actually be tempted to take a completely different approach to this, like having these objects contain some pseudo-unique "ID".

You could generate this by simply incrementing and evaluating some `static` "next ID counter" on construction. Then all you need to do is compare IDs, and no pointer comparisons come into it at all.

Your "next ID counter" will wrap around eventually, but are you going to have 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 buttons in your program's lifetime? Probably not.

If you *are* going to have many of these objects, though, and the additional space taken by the new member is a problem, then you can fall back on something like what molbdnilo showed.